# Search by multiple fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm working on a project and implemented a search by multiple fields in MVC, using LINQ like so:

```
public ActionResult SearchResult(SearchViewModel model)
{
    List<Requisition> emptyList = new List<Requisition>();

    if (model.RequisitionID > 0 
        || model.Department > 0 
        || model.Status > 0
        || model.RequisitionedBy != null)
    {
        var results = db.Requisitions.Where(x => x.RequisitionId > 0);

        results = ProcessSearchInput(model, results);

        return PartialView(results.ToList());
    }

    return PartialView(emptyList);
}
```

Helper:

```
private static IQueryable<Requisition> ProcessSearchInput(SearchViewModel model, IQueryable<Requisition> results)
{
    if (model.Department > 0)
        results = results.Where(x => x.Department == model.Department);

    if (model.RequisitionedBy != null)
        results = results.Where(x => x.Requisitioned_By.Contains(model.RequisitionedBy));

    if (model.Status > 0)
        results = results.Where(x => x.Status.Contains(model.Status.ToString()));

    return results;
}
```

This code works fine. 
However, if I add an extra search field to the form, I would also need to add a separate if statement in the controller. 
With the current approach, the ProcessSearchInput method will contain too many if statements.

Is there a better way to handle a search with multiple fields?

Comment: What is the problem with too many if-statements if it serves its purpose? You can always refactor and separate similar statements into a function. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-dynamic-filtering-and-sorting-with-entity-framework

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having "too many" if statements. You could create a generic function to perform search on each user input based on its data type, but I wouldn't recommend it. Code readability is important too.

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for Dynamic Linq which allows you to use a string in the Where clause. I even have a javascript widget called [Interactive Search Builder for javascript](https://github.com/crowcoder/ISBjs) that will generate a properly formatted dynamic linq clause. This would alleviate the need to change your code if you decide to add a new searchable field.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I wasn't sure if it was the right way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current approach violates the open closed principle. The solution is to create a dynamic filter like in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq) example. However that is a complicated solution that is worth only if you are going to add more and more filters along the way. If not then don't bother.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous comments: your current solution is probably the way to go.
In the real world, you'll soon have to implement filters like 'all customers having either a billing- or a shipping-address in New York', and more complicated stuff. By then, all clever generic stuff will just be in the way.

However, if you promise never to use this in production code:
you can save a lot of typing by using a query by example, where you specify the filter as an instance of the type your source contains:

```
var example = new Requisition { Department = 8, Requisitioned_By ="john" };
var result = db.Requisitions.FilterByExample(example);
```

This is a simple implementation:

```
public static class FilterByExampleHelper
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterByExample<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, T example) where T : class
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.CanRead))
        {
            ConstantExpression valueEx = null;
            var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
            if (propertyType.IsValueType)
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(example);
                if (value != null &&
                    !value.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType)))
                {
                    valueEx = Expression.Constant(value, propertyType);
                }
            }
            if (propertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(example) as string;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    valueEx = Expression.Constant(value);
                }
            }
            if (valueEx == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var parameterEx = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)); 
            var propertyEx = Expression.Property(parameterEx, property);
            var equalsEx = Expression.Equal(propertyEx, valueEx);
            var lambdaEx = Expression.Lambda(equalsEx, parameterEx) as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
            source = source.Where(lambdaEx);

        }
        return source;
    }
}
```